# "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" Javascript error when trying to add attribute terms from add product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

I am using the [Variation Swatches for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/variation-swatches-for-woocommerce/) plugin to display swatches for product attributes, but whenever I try to add terms to a product attribute in product add page I get the following javascript error:

```
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,underscore,backbone,wp-util,&load[]=wp-backbone,media-models,plupload&ver=4.8.1:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at Function.m.template (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,underscore,backbone,wp-util,&load[]=wp-backbone,media-models,plupload&ver=4.8.1:59)
at load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,underscore,backbone,wp-util,&load[]=wp-backbone,media-models,plupload&ver=4.8.1:63
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (admin.js?ver=20170113:71)
at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,underscore,backbone,wp-util,&load[]=wp-backbone,media-models,plupload&ver=4.8.1:3)
at HTMLBodyElement.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,underscore,backbone,wp-util,&load[]=wp-backbone,media-models,plupload&ver=4.8.1:3)
```

And the add term dialog don't show, but the same functionality works in the edit product page.

what can be the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like this is the problem of some 3rd party library or plugin.

Comment: I figured out the problem it's a minor bug in the plugin code will post an answer including the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a minor bug in the [Variation Swatches for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/variation-swatches-for-woocommerce/) plugin, the add term modal html wasn't being included in the add product page as a result of wrong conditional statement in the `class-admin.php` file on line 266:

```
if ( $pagenow != 'post.php' || ( isset( $post ) && get_post_type( $post->ID ) != 'product' ) )
```

This condition doesn't check for the add product page so to fix it we need to add the `post-new.php` page as an accepted page using this statement:

```
if ( ($pagenow != 'post.php' && $pagenow != 'post-new.php') || ( isset( $post ) && get_post_type( $post->ID ) != 'product' ) )
```